# Работа позиционирования в методе animate() jquery

Tags: jquery, position, animate, javascript, css

Всем привет.
Существует след. разметка:

```
<div class=content>     <h1>Какой-то текст</h1>     <p>     Неспроста свинцовый сосуд мгновенно открывает квазиупругую колбу. Карусель быстра и кратковременна. Часто бывает, что ядерная лапка груба и продуманна. Очевидно, феноменальная шестерня брезентового комплекта бережно увеличивает тайную лампу. Изящное значение резко и метастабильно. Платиновая инерция перегоревшего изолятора образовывает разделение.   </p> </div> <p><button>Изменить</button></p>
```

У ней след. стили:

```
.content{
            width: 400px;
            background: yellow;
            padding: 2em;
            position: relative;
        }
```

У не работает след. скрипт:

```
$('button').on("click", function(){
                $('.content').css({
                'left':'500px',
                'position':'absolute',
                });
            });
```

Вопрос:
Почему когда в место метода css ставлю метод animate() не срабатывает абсолютное позиционирование?
Спасибо умным людям, которые мне ответят.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

А что если попробовать так:

```
$('.content').css({'position':'absolute'}).animate({'left':'500px'});
```

---

Из оф. документации:

> The .animate() method allows us to
> create animation effects on any
> numeric CSS property. The only
> required parameter is a plain object
> of CSS properties. This object is
> similar to the one that can be sent to
> the .css() method, except that the
> range of properties is more
> restrictive.
>
> Animation Properties and Values
>
> All animated properties should be
> animated to a single numeric value,
> except as noted below; most properties
> that are non-numeric cannot be
> animated using basic jQuery
> functionality (For example, width,
> height, or left can be animated but
> background-color cannot be, unless the
> jQuery.Color() plugin is used).
> Property values are treated as a
> number of pixels unless otherwise
> specified. The units em and % can be
> specified where applicable.

Если вкратце - то animate работает только с теми свойствами, значения которых - числа.

Comment: Меня волнует именно то почему с одним методом абсолютное позиционирование работает, а с др. нет